# Is the force on a magnet between two magnets of same size and strength additive?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, vectors

Two bar magnets are in line with each other with their north and south poles near but not touching and they are secured in place. A third magnet is placed in the center air gap but perpendicular. Lets assume the magnets have a strength of 10k gauss. The center magnet will be repelled by one and attracted to the other depending on which pole is placed near. Would the attracting and repelling forces be additive or would the center magnet become saturated and only be able to sustain 10k gauss? 
[image: Three Magnets with one perpendicular]

Comment: Mass is not a measure of force. Additionally, pounds or "lbs" are a unit used only in certain regions (I'm guessing you're from the U.S.?) You're better off using SI units in the context of physics.

Comment: The question is relating to a simple concept. Lbs was used because magnet suppliers give them as an example of their strength in the US. I am only concerned with whether the force is additive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a good approximation, the magnetic field inside the magnets remains unchanged, even in the presence of other magnets. The forces are additive.